# Excel to HTML with calculations intact

Tags: calculator

I have a tax return calculator specific for my consultant website that was built in Excel. I need to put this calculator, with it's formats and formulas, into a WordPress website, without showing formulas, or without it looking like a table/Excel file.

I also need it to be interactive. For example, if "a" is chosen, the calculations in cell "e17" are different than if "b" is chosen, and so forth.

I've been searching how to turn it into an HTML code, or a PHP code, but I'm not having any luck. Can anyone help give recommendations?